# Get collection query string

Tags: magento

I'm using the following code to get some data from a table.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('bannerslider/bannerslider')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_home',$this->_display)
    ->addOrder('position', 'ASC')
        ;
```

Just for my curiosity, I want to check the query that is executed here and I'm echo using this code

```
$collection->printLogQuery(true);

var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
```

Now, my problem is that the string

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `bannerslider` AS `main_table` WHERE (status = '1') AND (is_home = '0')
```

is not showing my last condition, addOrder but the collection is really ordered by position field, I checked that.

What I don't understand is why the order condition is not visible in the query.
Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason your order isn't showing is because the orders are added to the query during the load() method.
See `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load()`

```
public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    // ... removed for brevity

    $this->_renderFilters()
         ->_renderOrders()
         ->_renderLimit();

    $this->printLogQuery($printQuery, $logQuery);
    $data = $this->getData();

    // ... removed for brevity
}
```

If you would call `$collection->load(true)` you would see the SQL containing the order by clause.

Answer (score 4):

Working with collection try next things:

```
$collection->setOrder('position', 'ASC'); // main order setter
$collectioon->getSelect()->order('position asc'); // alternative order setter

$collection->load(); // some times you need to call load() to be sure your collection don't get changes later in some place
echo $collection->getSelect(); // to print query
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `addAtributeToSort()` method like this :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('bannerslider/bannerslider')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_home',$this->_display)
    ->addAtributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
```

This works on Magento CE 1.5.1, I hope it will for you.

Comment: The method `addAttributeToSort()` is only available on EAV based collections extending `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`. Since the query in the question is referring to attributes that must be part of the main table, it very probably is not an EAV based entity.

Comment: in addition to what @Vinai said, that Collection is not part on EAV entity. It's from a module with it's own table.